# "provide net" in gentoo init script doesn't work as I thought

Tags: networking, gentoo, init-script

I'm running into a strange (to me) problem.

I'm running a gentoo with two net interfaces: `enp5s0` (wired interface) and `wlan0` (wifi). When I try to run a program, for example `openvpn`, from its script in `/etc/init.d`, it outputs:

```
* WARNING: openvpn is scheduled to start when net.enp5s0 has started
```

and doesn't start if the  interface `enp5s0` is not started, even if the other interface is up.

In `/etc/init.d/openvpn`, I've got these lines:

```
depend() {
        need localmount net
        use dns
        after bootmisc
}
```

and in `/etc/init.d/net.enp5s0` and `/etc/init.d/net.wlan0` (which are in fact symlinks to `/etc/init.d/net.lo`, Gentoo deals with the name of the script to know what it should do):

```
depend()
{
        [...]

        case "${IFACE}" in
                lo|lo0) ;;
                *)
                        after net.lo net.lo0 dbus
                        provide net
                        ;;
        esac

        [...]
}
```

So, as I understand the case, whichever of my interface provides the `net` "capacity" (I don't have the correct/canonical word for it), and `openvpn` should only rely on this capacity, and not on a particular interface. The same problem occurs with all the program that have the `need net` dependency.

What am I missing here?

My `uname -a` if it can be of some help:

`Linux yavin 3.7.10-gentoo-r1 #2 SMP Sat Apr 20 16:27:52 CEST 2013 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 330 @ 2.13GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`

Comment: Maybe the code is cleverer than we expect and detects that your OpenVPN configuration is bound to the IP address of this interface only (is it?)?

Comment: Uh, no... If I remove the `need net` line in `/etc/init.d/openvpn`, the program actually starts and runs flawlessly. It uses a distinct interface `tap0` which is totally independent from the real interface through which the packets go. And notice that it's not only related to `openvpn` but to all the softwares that have the `need net` dependency.

Comment: @HaukeLaging But thanks for your comment, I'm going to make the appropriate precision in my question.

Comment: The only relative info I've found is http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-705993.html. But even if removing the `need net` dependency does work, I feel like it's not really a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so reading the comments in configuration files does work sometimes...

I was right supposing that `net` works as a "virtual dependency" in the sense that more than one service can actually provide it. And it is actually documented that way in the manual: http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=4. But in fact, this is configurable and this behavior is not the default (at least, I don't remember having modified it once).

The `/etc/rc.conf` file can be used to customise the way `init` and the init-scripts work. And there is an interesting option in it.

```
# Do we allow any started service in the runlevel to satisfy the dependency
# or do we want all of them regardless of state? For example, if net.eth0
# and net.eth1 are in the default runlevel then with rc_depend_strict="NO"
# both will be started, but services that depend on 'net' will work if either
# one comes up. With rc_depend_strict="YES" we would require them both to
# come up.
#rc_depend_strict="YES"
```

As you see, this is exactly what I need, and it was simply defaulted to the wrong value (from my point of view). Setting this option to NO solved my problem.

Before:

```
yavin ~ # /etc/init.d/openvpn ineed
 * Caching service dependencies ...             [ ok ]
fsck dmcrypt localmount sysfs net.wlan0 net.enp5s0
```

After (in the case `wlan0` is up; I guess I'd have `enp5s0` instead of `wlan0` if `enp5s0` were up):

```
yavin ~ # /etc/init.d/openvpn ineed
 * Caching service dependencies ...             [ ok ]
fsck dmcrypt localmount sysfs net.wlan0
```